# Any ways to back up the stuff on GCP properly?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have been suffering from losing all data on GCP after my gmail account is suspended and recovered. Does anyone can offer help on advising how to back up the stuff on GCP properly? Many thanks.

BR,
Grace Lam

Comment: Each GCP product has own backup options. Please provide more details or at least list of GCP products that you're using.

Comment: It's a good idea to use separate accounts for billing and usage purposes within your project.